# submit button refresh form page only

Tags: laravel

i laravel project i have a form with `action="{{route('order.store')}}"` but when i click submit button the form page refresh instead of going to the route

```
<form action="{{route('orders.store')}}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="use_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{ $product->id }}">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i> Add To Cart</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: validation error?

Comment: show your routes?

Comment: i put name="use_id" instead of "user_id"

Comment: but there is no point in this line `<input type="hidden" name="use_id" value="{{ auth()->user()->id }}">` You are just asking for the user to change the ID to some other user's ID.  Leave this field off the form and use `auth()->id()` in the controller method to ensure records can only be created by the authenticated user